# Using DirectX within a Dll

Tags: c++, dll, directx

I am trying to create a Dll that will handle all my rendering, I am trying to initialize Direct X but I am getting the following error message:

> DXGI ERROR: CreateDXGIFactory cannot be called from DllMain. [ MISCELLANEOUS ERROR #76: ]
>   Exception thrown at 0x00007FF978181F28 in Engine.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: _com_error at memory location 0x000000541631BE90.

I never directly call CreateDXGIFactory, I only call D3D11CreateDevice before the program crashes, here is the code for D3D11CreateDevice:

```
HRESULT hRes;
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevel;
    m_pConsole->WriteToConsole("Creating D3D11 device !");
    hRes = D3D11CreateDevice(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG, NULL, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &m_pD3D11Device, &featureLevel, &m_pD3D11DeviceContext);
```

This function call is not in Dll main it is in an initialize function that is in its own class within the Dll.

Comment: where and when is the class initialize function is called?

Comment: `D3D11CreateDevice` with `pAdapter=NULL` (the first parameter) causes an internal call to `CreateDXGIFactory`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DllMain` is a special-case, so you have to be careful about what you do in it. For example, it gets called for *every thread* that is created in your process by default. Creating COM objects inside a `DllMain` is not safe because COM creation often involves loading other DLLs and you end up with a 'loader lock' problem. For more information on this see [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971.aspx)

Your best option here is to have an explicit initialization method which handles creating the Direct3D device that you call explicitly from your main application exe.

Comment: Thanks for the help I have fixed it now, I was calling the initialize function from a constructor in the exe.